# Where clause with fetch next row

Tags: sql, sql-server, codeigniter

How to user where clause with fetch next in sql query. My query ends like:

```
 10 ROWS FETCH NEXT 5 ROWS ONLY WHERE table.FullName LIKE '%name%'
```

Am getting error in where clause.

[error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CZ4rC.png)

> Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'WHERE'

**EDIT:**

```
select * 
from table name  
WHERE FullName LIKE '%name%' 
ORDER BY FullName 
OFFSET 10 ROWS FETCH NEXT 5 ROWS ONLY
```

The query will work when i remove the statement `'OFFSET 10 ROWS FETCH NEXT 5 ROWS ONLY'`

Comment: Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'WHERE'. This is the error

Comment: select * from table name  WHERE FullName LIKE '%name%' ORDER BY FullName OFFSET 10 ROWS FETCH NEXT 5 ROWS ONLY

Answer (score 1):

You probably have the wrong order of clauses and you need sort your result first to get stable resultset:

```
SELECT *
FROM ...
WHERE table.FullName LIKE '%name%'
ORDER BY ...
OFFSET 10 ROWS FETCH NEXT 5 ROWS ONLY
```

<kbd>**[`LiveDemo`](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/384198)**</kbd>

Keep in mind that `%phrase%` is **non-SARGable** and the query will have poor performance for big tables.

**`OFFSET FETCH`** will work only with **SQL Server 2012+**

Comment: I tried this am getting error like Invalid usage of the option NEXT in the FETCH statement.Actually am fetching 5 rows, but my search result has only one value.

Comment: @Youv SQL Server version?

Comment: Does the query work if  the search result (no:of records) is less than 5?

Comment: @Youv Run `select @@Version`

Comment: Am using this offset fetch in ssms 2014.It is working fine for me, but when i used this where clause like '%gg%', the thing is not working

Comment: Microsoft SQL Server 2014 - 12.0.2000.8 (X64) .This is the version

Comment: @Youv Is this entire query or you use for example `CURSOR`?

Comment: SELECT * from table WHERE FullName LIKE '%name%' ORDER BY FullName OFFSET 10 ROWS FETCH NEXT 5 ROWS ONLY This is my query

Comment: @Youv Post screenshot of your query and error. This is interesting case but I need to recreate it to help

Comment: Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 1
Incorrect syntax near 'OFFSET'.
Msg 153, Level 15, State 2, Line 1
Invalid usage of the option NEXT in the FETCH statement.

Comment: @Youv Will share screenshot or not? I've know this error already but I need broader view

Comment: @Youv Sorry but is it a joke? I see the error message from beginning. I need to see **actual data and query**

Comment: ie the only query am having , i just edited the table names and parameters.Am in the middle of something serious , am not joking.

Comment: how can i remove the where condition if it is null in model itself

Comment: @Youv If you suspect that `Am in the middle of something serious , am not joking` and you don't want to share here, write to Microsoft SQL Server support **https://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/**

Comment: @ lad2025 Actually i meant that i replied seriously and  i was not in a mood to joke.

Comment: @Youv : I am facing the same problem.. did you come out of any solution?

Answer (score 0):

You can not do an aggregate function on a SELECT *, you must specify the name of the column in either the SELECT clause or fully qualified name in the WHERE clause table_name.shemaname.columnname